Django QuerySet: how to aggregate repeated elements and add quantity field to it?
I have a feeling the solution to this is very simple, but as new to Django I am not able to figure it out...
Given the following QuerySet:
<QuerySet [
{'id': 2, 'prodclassQuery_id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('6.50')}, 
{'id': 1, 'prodclassQuery_id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50')}, 
{'id': 3, 'prodclassQuery_id': 2, 'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidades', 'prodPrice': Decimal('8.00')}, 
{'id': 3, 'prodclassQuery_id': 2, 'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidades', 'prodPrice': Decimal('8.00')}]>

I want to aggregate the repeated elements (based on id) e produce the following QuerySet, adding the field poQty_ to represent the quantity of repeated elements (products in my case...):
<QuerySet [
{'id': 2, 'prodclassQuery_id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('6.50'), 'poQty_': 1}, 
{'id': 1, 'prodclassQuery_id': 1, 'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml', 'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50'), 'poQty_': 1}, 
{'id': 3, 'prodclassQuery_id': 2, 'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidades', 'prodPrice': Decimal('8.00'), 'poQty_': 2}]>

What I tried so far with annotate() in views.py is not working, and the results of orders_aggris the same original QuerySet:
def display_orders(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('id', 'orderTable', 'menuQuery')
    for j in orders:
        print(j.prodQuery.values(),) # original QuerySet
    orders_aggr = Order.objects.annotate(poQty_=Count('prodQuery__id')).order_by('id', 'orderTable', 'menuQuery')
    for j in orders_aggr:
        print(j.prodQuery.values(),)
    context = {
        'orders': orders,
        'orders_aggr': orders_aggr
    }
    return render(request, 'orders.html', context)

Would anyone give please some help? Thanks !!
Further information:
models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    prodclassQuery = models.ForeignKey(ProductClass, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Product Class', default=1)
    prodDescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Product')
    prodPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Price')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['prodclassQuery', 'prodDescription']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.prodDescription

class Menu(models.Model):
    menuActive = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Active?', default=False)
    menuDescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Menu')
    prodQuery = models.ManyToManyField(Product, verbose_name='Product')
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['menuDescription',]
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.menuDescription
    
class Order(models.Model):
    orderUser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    orderDtOpen = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    orderDtClose = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    orderOpen = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Open?')
    orderTable = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Table')
    menuQuery = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Menu', default=1)
    prodQuery = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ProductOrder')

    class Meta:
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['orderTable'], condition=models.Q(orderOpen=True), name='unique_open_order_table',
                                violation_error_message='This table has already a open order')
        
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.orderuser = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    
class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    poOrder = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Order', default=1)
    poStatus = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Order Status')
    prodQuery = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Product', default=1)


Please let me know if my updated answer worked as expected, as the other answers don't seem to work as they count order IDs and not product IDs.

You can also use a combination of values()
and annotate(), so:

from django.db.models import Count

def display_orders(request):
    orders = Order.objects.values(
        'id',
        'orderTable',
        'menuQuery'
    ).annotate(
        poQty_=Count('id')
    ).order_by(
        'id',
        'orderTable',
        'menuQuery'
    )

    context = {
        'orders': orders,
    }
    return render(request, 'orders.html', context)

This code will group the orders by the specified fields (id, orderTable, menuQuery), count the distinct occurrences of each group, and annotate the count onto each result.

Try something like that:
def display_orders(request):
  orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('id', 'orderTable', 'menuQuery')
  orders_aux = [j for i in orders for j in i.prodQuery.values()]  
  orders_aux1 = []
  orders_aggr = []
  for i in orders_aux:
    if i['id'] not in orders_aux1:
      orders_aux1.append(i['id'])
      i['poQty_'] = 1
      orders_aggr.append(i)
    else:
      orders_aggr[orders_aux1.index(i['id'])]['poQty_'] += 1
  context = {
      'orders': orders,
      'orders_aggr': orders_aggr
  }
  return render(request, 'orders.html', context) 

Result:
print(orders_aggr)

[{'id': 2,
  'prodclassQuery_id': 1,
  'prodDescription': 'Hofbräu Kellerbier 500 ml',
  'prodPrice': Decimal('6.50'),
  'poQty_': 1},
 {'id': 1,
  'prodclassQuery_id': 1,
  'prodDescription': 'Tonic Water 300 ml',
  'prodPrice': Decimal('4.50'),
  'poQty_': 1},
 {'id': 3,
  'prodclassQuery_id': 2,
  'prodDescription': 'Coxinha 6 unidades',
  'prodPrice': Decimal('8.00'),
  'poQty_': 2}]

Note that queryset now is a list of objects. I personally prefer to do things like this inside the get_context_data method.

A few things, first, in display_orders you're evaluating the queryset for Orders.objects more than once, which is redundant
I think if you modified the display_orders view to look something like this
def display_orders(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all().order_by(
        'id',
        'orderTable',
        'menuQuery'
    ).distinct('id').annotate(
        poQty_=Count('id')
    )


    context = {
        'orders': orders,
    }
    return render(request, 'orders.html', context)

The annotation should count the distinct line items, and tac on that count to each result
The call to distinct should also remove the duplicates from the queryset

Thanks @Ozzie, elegant solution, but it did not work as distinct(*field) is not supported in MySQL. I get an error: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
